# Dynamic steps in pipeline parallel doesn't work as expected

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I try to create dynamically parallel steps in Jenkins pipeline from collection.

When I run ***sh*** code block without assignment to variable everything works fine.
When I assign ***sh*** code to variable and then trying to execute it - then for each parallel step code use last element in collection.

```
CLUSTERS="192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2|127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2"
```

Work as expected:

```
stage("Run Repair") {
  environment { CLUSTERS = findClusters() }
  steps {
    script {
      def splitted_clusters = CLUSTERS.split('\\|')
      def stepsForParallel = splitted_clusters.collectEntries {
        echo "Non parallel ${it}"
        ["Repair ${it}" : {sh(script: """ echo "parallel: Found cluster with IPs: ${it}" """)}]
      }
      echo "Start parallel:"
      parallel stepsForParallel
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Non parallel 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2
Non parallel 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
Start parallel:
[Repair 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2] Running shell script
[Repair 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2] Found cluster with IPs: 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2
[Repair 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2] Running shell script
[Repair 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2] Found cluster with IPs: 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
```

Doesn't work:

```
stage("Run Repair") {
  environment { CLUSTERS = findClusters() }
  steps {
    script {
      def splitted_clusters = CLUSTERS.split('\\|')
      def stepsForParallel = splitted_clusters.collectEntries {
        command = """ echo "Found cluster with IPs: ${it}" """
        echo "Non parallel ${it}"
        ["Repair ${it}" : {sh(script: command)}]
      }
      echo "Start parallel:"
      parallel stepsForParallel
    }
  }
}
```

Wrong output:

```
Non parallel 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2
Non parallel 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
Start parallel:
[Repair 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2] Running shell script
[Repair 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2] Found cluster with IPs: 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
[Repair 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2] Running shell script
[Repair 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2] Found cluster with IPs: 127.0.0.1,127.0.0.2
```

So, I try to understand what hides behind this behavior?